# How do i calculate the distance between two nodes using time taken for the packet to be sent across?

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

Let's say I have two nodes, one sends a packet across to the other node. How do i calculate the distance between them using the time taken? I'm pretty sure I have to use the distance = speed*time formula, which I am. My code is as follows

**Node1.cc**

```
socket.sendTo(payload, destAddr, destPort);
    auto const result = SEND_TIME_HISTORY.insert(std::make_pair(numSent, simTime().dbl()));
            if (not result.second) {
                result.first->second = simTime().dbl();
            }
```

What that does is basically each time it sends a packet it stores its current simTime and sequence number inside a map, so im sure that im calculating from the correct sequence of packets

**Node2.cc**

```
map<int, double> SENT_TIME_HISTORY =
                Node1->returnTimeHistory(); //basicaly retrieve the map
        for (std::map<int, double>::iterator iter = SENT_TIME_HISTORY.begin();
                iter != SENT_TIME_HISTORY.end(); iter++) {

            //iterate through and check if the received sequence number matches the sent sequence number
            if (rcvseq == iter->first){

                //host_currenttime is simTime().dbl() as soon as the packet is received
                timediff = host_currenttime - iter->second; 
                cout << "Time received: " << host_currenttime << "\tTime sent: " << iter->second <<"\tActual time taken" << timediff << endl;
            }
        }
cout << "Calculated distance: " << timediff*299792458 << endl;
```

Basically the output is rubbish. Right now I am taking the time taken for the packet to be sent across multiplied by the speed of light to determine the distance. Am I doing something wrong here?

If more source code is necessary please do inform me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Finding distance by time taken would be inaccurate with WiFi due to the fact that it uses Csma Ca (Inet/linklayer/csmaca). Its is technically a queue for the host to wait for it's time to send to the AP and for the AP to broadcast the message.
This report has a great write up on the Impact of csmaca https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.04604.pdf

You would have to create your own linklayer if you want to calculate the distance by speed.

Answer (score 0):

There a many factors that add to the latency of a packet sent from one node to the other, most of them non-deterministic. So the approach outlined above will not deliver satisfying results at all, unfortunately.

This does not mean, however, that it is impossible to calculate the distance between two nodes by means of Wi-Fi.

Wi-Fi Alliance, the governing body of Wi-Fi, has a certification program named “Wi-Fi location”, that is based on the IEEE 802.11mc standard amendment and specifies the localization of Wi-Fi client by Fine Time Measurement (FTM).

On a very high level, the access points that support Wi-Fi location add time information to their management frames that the clients can evaluate. A client needs to “see” at least three access points to calculate its position.

More information can be found here: https://www.wi-fi.org/discover-wi-fi/wi-fi-location